# Suspicious Traffic Find IP on Azure Web App

Tags: azure-web-app-service, appinsights

I have noticed in my app insights log some suspicious traffic and I would like to block the IP. However, all I find is 0.0.0.0 for the IP on all requests. Is there a way to find in a log the exact IP to block future requests from the IP? I am using an Azure Web App with App Insights turned on for .Net Core application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [enabled Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#send-logs-to-azure-monitor-preview) for AppServiceHTTPLogs and AppServiceIPSecAuditLogs. These logs should contain the source IP address.